# How is JSON pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, terminology

I watched a video on https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-pronounce-JSON and read some sites, but don't understand, what letter is emphasized (accentuated, stressed): jAy sawn or jay sAwn?

Comment: I mean, I pronounce it like the name 'Jason', but I think this would be better on a relevant tech SE.

Comment: You could probably make this a better fit for this site as opposed to, say, [softwareengineering.se] by adding what answers on Quora said about how to pronounce it, especially the weird-looking IPA transcriptions, and how you're still struggling with that.

Comment: always imagined it was "JAY-sawn", "The end is like the O in on", (from https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2mapkc/how_to_pronounce_json/ )

Comment: The short answer from EL&U questions like *[What's the correct pronunciation of BIOS?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283582)* and *[How to pronounce “Linux”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38003)* is that there are multiple ways to pronounce these contrived words accepted by different knowledgeable people. I deliberately pronounce it with equal stress and a drawn-out second syllable to avoid sounding like the given name *Jason*; others do quite the opposite.

Comment: Personally, I say "jay-Sahn", with equal stress, and the second syllable rhymes with "con", not "lawn".

Comment: I pronounce it in a way that rhymes with caisson, like jaisson. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caisson

Comment: @Hellion Wait. How do you pronounce "con" and "lawn"?  Those rhyme to me

Comment: @Kevin well, how about "father" vs. "ball"?  Of course if you have the [Cot-Caught merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_open_back_vowels#Cot.E2.80.93caught_merger) it may not matter.  For a sample of the sounds, try https://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/ and listen to the two "Open / Back" sounds.  "jay-Sahn" uses /ɑ/, not /ɒ/ .

Comment: @Hellion Interesting. Evidently I have the Cot-Caught merge

Comment: I first started using JSON in a team that included a guy named Jason (and the Cot-Caught merge is typical in the local dialect), so we all definitely stressed the second syllable to reduce confusion with the name.

Comment: @CanadianYankee, hah, an interesting story!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most often jay-suhn, like the name and the video, or jay-sawn, emphasis on the second syllable.

Lately, most people I've heard use the latter.  I suspect to specifically differentiate it from the name.

Whatever you do, never write JASON, eeek.

Comment: Thanks! As I understood, in most cases second syllable is emphasized. I didn't know, whether it was most common.